# Input с выпадающим списком выбора кода оператора

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, input

Как реализовать инпут, при нажатии на который появлялся бы выпадающий список с возможностью выбора оператора.

Нашел вот такое решение, с использованием database:

```html
<input name="city" list="cities" />
<datalist id="cities">
   <option value="Naples" />
   <option value="London" />
   <option value="Berlin" />
   <option value="New York" />
   <option value="Frattamaggiore" />
</datalist>
```

Но этот способ больше подходит для автозаполнения, а мне нужно чтобы просто можно было выбрать код оператора и он записался в инпут. Может есть у кого готовое решение или какая-то библиотека?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('select#cities').on('change', function() {
  $('input[name="city"]').val(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="city" />
<select id="cities">
   <option value="Naples">Naples</option>
   <option value="London">London</option>
   <option value="Berlin">Berlin</option>
   <option value="New York">New York</option>
   <option value="Frattamaggiore">Frattamaggiore</option>
</select>
```

Comment: @Regent спасибо за замечание. обновил ответ